# Equations of Motion in Cylindrical Co-ordinates

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential, cylindrical-coordinates

I've run into an interesting set of differential equations, that I'm not 100% sure where to begin- I'm not looking for a 100% complete solution, more just a push in the right direction of where I can start:

The question is as follows:

Consider a particle of unit mass moving within the z=0 plane in a central potential field

$$U(r)=-\frac{1}r$$
where r is the distance from the centre

Initially, I had to explain why the cylindrical system $(r, \phi, z)$
was most suitable.
Following this, I had to derive an expression for the force field, using
$$ \vec F = -gradU $$

I obtained this with no problem, achieveing 
$$ \vec F = -\frac{1}{r^2}\hat e_r $$

Finally, I had to use the fact that the acceleration vector in cylindrical co-ordinates was:

$$\vec a = (\ddot r - r\dot\phi^2)\hat e_r + (2\dot r\dot\phi + r\ddot \phi)\hat e_\theta + \ddot z \hat e_z $$
to find equations of motion for 
$r(t)$, and $ \phi(t) $

and then, show that $ \phi(t) $ will change linearly with time if the particle moves along a circular trajectory within the plane.

I started with Newton's equation:

$$ \vec F = m \vec a$$
such that

$$-\frac{1}{r^2}\hat e_r = m((\ddot r - r\dot\phi^2)\hat e_r + (2\dot r\dot\phi + r\ddot\phi)\hat e_\theta + \ddot z \hat e_z) $$

finally rounding off with the system of equations

$$ \ddot r - r\dot \phi^2 = -\frac{1}{mr^2}$$
$$ 2\dot r \dot\phi + r\ddot \phi = 0$$
$$ \ddot z = 0$$

Equation 2 was then rearranged to

$$ 2\frac{\dot r}r = -\frac{\ddot \phi}{\dot \phi}$$

Which, after integrating both sides, yielded:

$$ ln(|r^2|) = -ln(|\dot \phi|) + C$$

After some manipulation and simplification (and letting $C = ln(A)$): 
$$\dot \phi =\frac{A}{r^2}$$

From this, I substituted it into Equation 1, and rearranged, obtaining

$$mr^3 \ddot r + r = mA^2$$

I'm not too sure where to go from here to obtain a solution for $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$.

Any further hints will be appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384274/from-gravity-equation-of-motion-to-general-solution-in-polar-coordinates?rq=1.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why they've done $du/d\theta$ if the substitution is $r=1/u$ ? I don't see how u is a function of $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, observe that the third equation implies $z=0$ since your particle has initial position and velocity on $z=0$. The second equation can be written as
$$
(r^2\dot\phi)'=0
$$
therefore $r^2\dot\phi=C$ (this is the kinetic moment, an invariant of the motion related to Kepler's second law: it is twice the areolar velocity). This constant is defined by the initial conditions. Then you can replace $\dot\phi$ by $C/r^2$ on your first equation, which is an ODE for $r$ only.

Comment: Wouldn't that derivative lead to 2r*r' phi' + r^2 phi'' ? rather than what I have?

Comment: Just divide by $r$

Comment: Using that, I ended up with a nonlinear DE, that I'm not too familiar with solving (we haven't reached that chapter yet) so I'm a little perplexed as to what I do, and if there's potential substitutions to make to simplify it?

Comment: In addition, it's implying that I should have some finite solution (I believe), so the only method of solving nonlinear DEs (power series) that I know wouldn't really apply here, unless I'm mistaken